# Ionic 4: Cannot GET /

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Why do I get this error? I run the following commands in cmd:

```
ionic start pollito tabs

cd pollito
ionic server
```

> CMD: [INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!

> [ng] i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: / [ng] Date: 2019-05-04T05:20:49.125Z [ng] Hash: dc6d227d2df5e3578183 [ng] Time: 154003ms [ng] [ng] ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/global.scss)[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js): [ng] Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass' [ng] Require stack: [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\build-impl.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng [ng] at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15) [ng] at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27) [ng] at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19) [ng] at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16) [ng] at Object.sassLoader (C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72) [ng] ERROR in ./src/theme/variables.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/theme/variables.scss) [ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js): [ng] Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass' [ng] Require stack: [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\build-impl.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng [ng] at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15) [ng] at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27) [ng] at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19) [ng] at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16) [ng] at Object.sassLoader (C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72) [ng] ERROR in ./src/app/tab1/tab1.page.scss [ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js): [ng] Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass' [ng] Require stack: [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\build-impl.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js [ng] - C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng [ng] at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15) [ng] at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27) [ng] at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19) [ng] at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16) [ng] at Object.sassLoader (C:\Angel\pollito\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72) [ng] chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 20.2 kB [rendered] [ng] chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 284 kB [initial] [rendered] [ng] chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 32 kB [initial] [rendered] [ng] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 237 kB [initial] [rendered] [ng] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 8.9 kB [entry] [rendered] [ng] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 22.5 kB [initial] [rendered] [ng] chunk {tab1-tab1-module} tab1-tab1-module.js, tab1-tab1-module.js.map (tab1-tab1-module) 7.87 kB [rendered] [ng] chunk {tab2-tab2-module} tab2-tab2-module.js, tab2-tab2-module.js.map (tab2-tab2-module) 4.52 kB [rendered] [ng] chunk {tab3-tab3-module} tab3-tab3-module.js, tab3-tab3-module.js.map (tab3-tab3-module) 4.52 kB [rendered] [ng] chunk {tabs-tabs-module} tabs-tabs-module.js, tabs-tabs-module.js.map (tabs-tabs-module) 7.55 kB [rendered] [ng] chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.36 MB [initial] [rendered] [ng] i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Browser: Cannot GET /

Comment: sounds like environmental or dependency issue. i personally would make a clean install of framework to cure this.

Answer (score 15):

when you make the command ionic serve the project does not build up completely. To do this you must use the `ionic build` command.
If there is an error in your project, it may not be displayed when you run ionic serve! The project crashes and you get a "Cannot get" error on your browser.

In my case I just have to do `ionic build` to see what the error is and fix it. Then it works much better ;)

Comment: No idea why you have no up-votes, but this is the correct answer.

Comment: Yup, this is the most likely scenario

Answer (score 2):

This notice comes up when there's an error in your code while you're compiling for the first time. It won't show the error on the browser, but will give you `cannot GET /`.

You should check our browser console for the error, if you can't find, check the command prompt from which you ran `ionic serve`. You'll get more information about the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a %20 in your project path somewhere remove it/replace it with a space. That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: No idea why it was down-voted originally, but having a space in the folder name, rather than special char encoding, fixed the issue on macOS. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue and following solution fixed it for me:

1. Remove android platform: `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. Remove node_modules folder
3. Remove plugins folder
4. Run `npm install` command
5. Add android platform again: `ionic cordova platform add android`

Compile your app again.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I had this error when using

- the documents folder in my user directory for the app
- git bash (mingw64)

**I fixed this by**

- moving the app folder down to the root of C: drive under /Development/ folder
- just retrying same commands within gitbash (mingw64)

Seems Windows and its extra spaces in folders stuff caused this, maybe in combination with gitbash.

Answer (score -1):

```
Remove Path from app-routing.module.ts .
```

{
path: 'modal',
loadChildren: () => import('./modal/modal.module').then( m => m.ModalPageModule)
}